# how to align text in editors with shortcut keys just like in ms office

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, tinymce

In ms office in order to align text we first have to select the text than by pressing ctrl+L, ctrl+r, ctrl+e for left, right and center respectively we can align text.

But for online text editor say tinymce and cke editor I don't know what is the shortcut keys, there are icon from which we can do it but I want to know is there any shortcut keys.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has some default shortcuts like undo (Ctrl+Z), Bold (Ctrl+B) etc (see here: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=9445), but also has the ability for you to define functions that occur on specific keypresses.

Eg.

```
editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+a', function() {});
editor.shortcuts.add('meta+a', function() {}); // "meta" maps to Command on Mac and Ctrl on PC
editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+alt+a', function() {});
editor.shortcuts.add('access+a', function() {}); // "access" maps to ctrl+alt on Mac and shift+alt on PC
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.Shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

```
this is how my code looks   
 where can i add editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+a', function() {});
    $(document).ready(function()
    {tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea",
       plugins: [
        "textcolor advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen ",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages",
      ],
    relative_urls: false,
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | fontselect  | forecolor | backcolor | fontsizeselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages | fullscreen |preview | mybutton",
       setup: function(editor) {
            editor.addButton('mybutton', {
                text: 'Preview it!!!',
                icon: true,
                onclick: function(e) {
                editor.execCommand('mcePreview');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    });
```